# What is JavaScript Comma Operator

Tags: javascript

What is comma operator in JavaScript. If I execute

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
a,b
```

I get

```
2
```

Comment: Have you tried searching on Google for the answer? It turned out being the first result for query "What is JavaScript Comma Operator"...

Comment: where are you getting that value? how are you printing it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

More on: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Comment: Use authoritative sources for your answer, please.